# Check password on a pdf file without opening

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to make brute force attack method to find password on pdf files. I use this method to check password using **itextsharp**

```
public static bool IsPasswordValid(string pdfFullname, byte[] password) {
    try {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFullname, password);
        return true;
    } catch (BadPasswordException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works. But take very long time when the PDF file size is large. Is there a way check password without loading file to memory?.

Comment: Try [this overloaded constructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray,%20byte[],%20boolean%29).

Comment: @kuujinbo It's very helpful. but still have some time deference between small and large file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things.

First, in my [blog post here](http://cjhaas.com/blog/2011/10/13/speed-up-itextsharps-pdfreader-when-reading-multiple-files-or-one-very-large-file/) I found that using the constructor overload that takes a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` to be the fastest. I just tested again with source code that I've got sitting around (5.5.6.0) and it is still twice as fast as the string-based path method (for large files). However, that constructor overload is marked as `obsolete` and might in fact actually be removed in more recent versions so you'll need to deal/live with that.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdfFullname, true), password);
```

To be very clear, that overload was specifically removed for some reason so you might want to consider not using it.

Second, the question `Is there a way check password without loading file to memory?` is actually misleading. If memory were actually the bottleneck you'd have much bigger problems. I just did a quick test using `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()` on an 80MB file and it took about 90 milliseconds to load everything into memory and my computer is seven years old.

The actual speed problem is that iText needs to find the `trailer` of the PDF which has a pointer to the `/Encrypt` dictionary. Because iText is intended to be used to actually *do* something with a PDF it doesn't spend a whole lot of time optimizing this path because its going to have to happen eventually no matter what. If you really, really care about speed this is where I'd start. I'd recommend checking out [Adobe's spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) to see how the standard PDF encryption works, it's relatively simple. There's also a [great simplified description here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt).

If your goal is cracking you should be able to write a very crude password guesser that looks for the trailer, looks for and find the `/Encrypt` key and process the `/O` and `/U` keys. There's lots of "gotchas" in this if you haven't read the spec, for instance documents can have multiple `trailer` entries, there's alternatives to passwords, etc. but this should probably get you 99% of common PDFs out there.